# React recursive components - Children not rerendering properly

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, recursion, reactjs

I'm writing a series of components in react that will make a structure like this:

```
Field
  |_BasicField: plain input field.
  |_ListField: a list of Fields.
  |_Entity: a complex Field that can have BasicFields, ListFields
            and Entities as its children components.
```

The code for this structure you can find it [here in my repo](https://github.com/throoze/vendata/tree/feature/list/app/assets/javascripts/components/scraping).

The data used to generate the scraping form is [in this file](https://github.com/throoze/vendata/blob/feature/list/db/seeds.rb).

What happens is that once the first level of the form is rendered, children `Field`s are dynamically generated, but they don't seem to be rerendering as expected. I'm just trying to make sense out of it, and it seems to me that react had the children components cached in a previous state, but when the state updates it doesn't update the children components, but renders them as they where in the previous state, or something like that, I'm really lost here. I don't even know where to look for the error. Please any help will be really appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Can you expand on the problem? I'm having a hard time understanding your issue. Maybe some screens shots or code highlights?

Comment: Thanks for your concern. I solved this, it was a weird problem about how files and libraries were being imported (required). I solved it by moving all the components involved in the issue to a single file (`BasicField`, `ListField`, `Entity` and `Field`), and doing stuff like clearing the cache and deleting the `node_modules` directory and running `npm install again`, making sure that when running `npm ls react`, it only listed one `react` package, to avoid weird require errors. I really can't enumerate exactly what i did, but this issue was too mystic for me :P

Comment: [This commit](https://github.com/throoze/vendata/commit/e0c3b63ec2fadb70b3bcefb77e42840c1250a0bf) shows where the issue is solved. You can go from it backwards and try to track the changes if you are in a similar situation. I'm sorry I can't be more specific.